# Change the size of the image inside the javafx interface

Tags: java, javafx

I have got an image in my javafx software and I want to define its size from my code. The code where with which I am reading the pic is the following:

```
image= new Image(gui.getClass().getResourceAsStream("img.gif"));
imageIMG.setGraphic(new ImageView(image));
```

I want to define the size of this image in my GUI. When I am trying to setup the size I found out that I cannot use a method like `image.setHeight/Width`. Why I cannot define the size of the image? Is there any alternative way to do so?

**EDIT:** This is what I am performing to load the image in my graphics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `Image` in JavaFX is only a container for the image data.  You can scale the image at loading time (using another constructor) but this change is permanent (but can be useful to save memory).

When you want to display an `Image`, you wrap it in an `ImageView`.  This class has methods to scale the image dynamically, depending on where you need it.  It  won't change the underlying data.

`Image` can be re-used.  You can use the same `Image` in multiple `ImageView`s and show it at different sizes without having to have multiple copies of the same image loaded.

**Update**

```
image= new Image(gui.getClass().getResourceAsStream("img.gif"));
ImageView iv = new ImageView(image);
iv.setFitWidth(100);  // Change size
imageIMG.setGraphic(iv);
```

Comment: I am actually using setGraphic(new ImageView(image)); to load it to my interface but I am still not sure how can I change the size of the image.